# solve the differential equation $2y^{(5)}-7y^{(4)}+12y'''-8y''=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I cannot find the roots of the characteristic equation to get a solution.  I only know the basic way to solve these equations.  I factored out an $r^2$.

$2r^5-7r^4+12r^3-8r^2 = 0$

$r^2(2r^3-7r^2+12r-8) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $y^{\left(n\right)}\equiv\frac{\partial^{n}y}{\partial t^{n}}$.
Let $w=y^{\prime\prime}$ so that the equation becomes
$$
2w^{\prime\prime\prime}-7w^{\prime\prime}+12w^{\prime}-8w=0.
$$
The characteristic polynomial, as you pointed out, is
$$
2r^{3}-7r^{2}+12r-8
$$
with imaginary and real roots (solvable in $\mathbb{Q}$). As @Pieter21 points out, you can use Wolfram to get the roots; they are not "nice" numbers. Perhaps you can just use the approximate forms $1.2581$ and $1.210\pm 1.3867i$.

With a solution for $w$, you can derive a solution for $y$ since $y=\int\int w$.

Comment: The last number is -8 not +8

Comment: How did you get these values?  I tried every factor +-1, +-2, +-4, +-8. I also divided by 2 and tried the factors +-1, +-2, +-4.  Then I used synthetic division.  All of these roots have remainders.  I do not know any other way to find the roots of a 3rd degree equation other than to reduce it to a 2nd degree, then use the quadratic.

Comment: It does not have integer roots, and one of the roots is not even real. See the picture on the Wolfram page linked by @Pieter21.

Comment: Is there a way to get to these numbers on paper by hand?

Comment: Yes, but it involves the roots of a cubic polynomial. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function. This method has been around for a long time, so there's no problem with mentioning that you used some symbolic algebra package and just showing the roots.

Comment: I think I'm suppose to do it by hand.  It just says to solve the equation. There's nothing else involved after that.

Comment: Well. I'm not sure what else I can say... all of the tools are there.

Answer (score 0):

Check Wolfram alpha for further factorization.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E3-7x%5E2%2B12x-8%3D0&lk=4&num=2

Are you sure you have all signs right? Also the other answer?!